# Reading text file and comparing line with the exact same line returns false

Tags: php, arrays, file, loops, foreach

My current code:

```
$file = fopen("countries.txt","r");
$array = array();

while(!feof($file)) {
    $array[] = fgets($file);
}

fclose($file);
```

Here is my foreach loop:

```
$str = "test";

foreach ($array as $key => $val) {

    if ($val == $str) {
        echo $val;
    } else {
        echo "not found";
    }

}
```

I am wondering why it is only printing $val if it is the last value of the array.

For example, it works if the txt file looks like this

```
test1
test2
test3
test
```

but doesn't work if it looks like this

```
test1
test2
test
test3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is, that you have a new line character at the end of each line, so:

```
test\n !== test
  //^^ See here
```

That's why it doesn't work as you expect it to.

How to solve it now? Can I introduce to you the function: [`file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php). You can read a file into an array and set the flag to ignore these new lines at the end of each line.

So putting all this information together you will get this code:

```
$array = file("countries.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$str = "test";

foreach ($array as $key => $val) {

    if ($val == $str) {
        echo $val;
    } else {
        echo "not found";
    }

}
```

Comment: @user3038431 You're welcome. (BTW: If you use your old code and then do: `var_dump($array);` <- Look at the quotes, see the end quote on the new line ? That shows you, that there is a new line character at the end)

Answer (score 0):

When you compare strings - you should always use '==='.